# Integrate AMAZON CONGNITO with GRAILS 3 and spring-security-core

Tags: grails, amazon-cognito, grails-spring-security

I am looking to start a new project on GRAILS 3 which will use Amazon CONGNITO and spring-security-core. The main objective is to use Amazon CONGNITO user pool as a centralized user auth for both GRAILS 3 application which will include spring-security-core and for the ANGULAR API.

Is there any plugin that I can use quickly to integrate all three and start developing the application?